# Can I pull data from a .xls file with PHP, sort and call the data without MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'm learning basic PHP at this point. I have a .xls (Excel, converted from Numbers on the mac) file that I want to call upon for data.

Currently the table has 3 columns: Team Name, Conference and Division and for each column there are 32 total rows (not including the row for labels)

My goal with this simple program is to read in this table, and build a simple UI so that when I click on a Division, it shows the four teams in that division.

Can this be done without MySql? Should I be reading the .xls file into the .html file where the user will interact with the buttons or into the .php file that the .html file links to.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file in Excel, go to File, and click on Save As, you'll get a normal save dialog. Here, select .csv, rather than .xls. This is a format both PHP and Excel understand.

Call [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the data from the file into an array, and [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write one of these arrays (modified if required) to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

There [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) which can read/write .xls files (actual native .xls, not .csv renamed to .xls).

Answer (score 0):

For reading xls files, you can try smt like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/). However, in my opinion, it would be much easier if you save your xls as csv, and then read it.

For the no-mysql part, you can create your own data structure and use it like that. You could use multidimensional arrays for that purpose.

If speed is the key, you should sort the data based on a certain column for quicker searching (you could then use binary search). Or, even better, you could use hash tables.

Here is a description on csv reading: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: So I've saved the document as a .csv file. I'm not that advanced yet.

Comment: Not quite sure from here how to now read that .csv file into an array

Comment: do you know how to read a file in php? if you do, simply go line by line (skipping the first line, because you probably have column names in it) and use explode function to break the current row into an array. check the link i posted in my answer

Comment: I don't know how to read a file in php yet. Would you mind helping me with a code snippit or two? Once I read the code I can learn it and internalize it

Comment: Ok, please check the link regarding fgetcsv. You will find an example there, and it should get you started.